# How to make giant chart from values in java. (NetBeans)

Tags: java, netbeans

I am making a project, in which I am getting real time values of process, burst time etc. which will helps teachers and students to understand better,
I am able to get values and to show in dialog box, Now I want to show values in graphically (picture is attached). Kindly suggest.
In first picture, I am displaying result, second picture is sample, like this 
I want to show values. Thanks

[image: Here I am displaying result]

[image: and I want to show data like this]

Comment: Have you tried writing any code?  As it is, your question is asking to recommend a library or something - which is off topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: No, I didn't tried for any code or library, because I totally don't know what to write or use library, Totally untouched with such kind of graphics. :-(

Comment: and I accept this is off the topic question from stack overflow, because no code.